# java Converting a set to an array

Tags: java

I'm trying to convert my set of Strings to an array of Strings so I can operate on them one by one. Is there a better way of doing this or is converting to arrays a good way? However, when I try converting to an array like below then I get errors as it doesn't think that it will always be strings passed in. Would appreciate some pointers.

```
Set<String> s;

s.add("a");
s.add("b");
String[] item =  s.toArray();
```

Comment: The reason you get errors is because `toArray` with no arguments returns an `Object[]`.  You need to give it an argument, even a dummy argument like `new String[0]`, in order to get it to return an array of something else.  See the javadoc [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#toArray(T[])).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have to convert a `Set` to an array just to operate on the elements.  You can iterate over the elements directly

```
Set<String> s = new HashSet<>();
....
for (String item : s)
{
    do something...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
so I can operate on them one by one
```

You don't have to convert it to an array for that.

Instead iterate using the for-each loop or the iterator.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this

```
String[] item = s.toArray(new String[s.size()]);
```

As per Java doc - toArray function ( which is the one you need )

> toArray() Returns an array containing all of the elements in this list
>   in proper sequence (from first to last element).